# avoid hibernate logs from printing on jboss console

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, jboss

I m using jboss as application server, it very irritating when I am deploy my application on jboss server it printing hibernate logs like

```
"FINE: ----- beginning hibernate tx 32213345 --------------------------------------------------------
16:37:27,716 ERROR [STDERR] 6 Dec, 2010 4:37:27 PM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log info
INFO: jBPM version info: library[4.3], schema[4.3]
16:37:27,717 ERROR [STDERR] 6 Dec, 2010 4:37:27 PM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log debug
FINE: ----- committing hibernate tx 22527471 -------------------------------------------------------
16:37:27,719 INFO  [STDOUT] 16:37:27,719 INFO  [ProcessExecutionFactory] Exiting ServiceExecutionIntf with return value .....null(org.jbpm.test.ProcessExecutionProviderImpl)
16:37:27,762 ERROR [STDERR] 6 Dec, 2010 4:37:27 PM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log debug
FINE: ----- beginning hibernate tx 19486230 --------------------------------------------------------
16:37:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] 6 Dec, 2010 4:37:27 PM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log debug
FINE: ----- committing hibernate tx 2165098 -------------------------------------------------------
16:37:27,926 ERROR [STDERR] 6 Dec, 2010 4:37:27 PM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log debug
FINE: ----- beginning hibernate tx 26648124 --------------------------------------------------------
16:37:28,001 ERROR [STDERR] 6 Dec, 2010 4:37:28 PM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log debug
FINE: ----- committing hibernate tx 9901286 -------------------------------------------------------
16:37:28,018 ERROR [STDERR] 6 Dec, 2010 4:37:28 PM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log debug
FINE: ----- beginning hibernate tx 11762369 --------------------------------------------------------
16:37:28,185 ERROR [STDERR] 6 Dec, 2010 4:37:28 PM org.jbpm.internal.log.Jdk14Log debug
FINE: ----- committing hibernate tx 7629906 -------------------------------------------------------
"
```

So, is any way to avoid it from printing on jboss server?
If so, then plz. r'ply me as soon as possible.

thank you.

Comment: All these log messages are at the error level and so, are serious matter, I think it is good to see them printed so it catches your attention.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is a problem with your log configuration. Is there any information in your JBoss log that it wasn't able to open the log file?

Apart from that issue, JBoss configures the log output per instance. You can find the configuration file in, e.g., for the default instance, `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/conf/jboss-log4j.xml`. Inside this file you find a general section about Hibernate. For example:

```
<!-- Limit the verbose hibernate categories -->
<category name="org.hibernate">
   <priority value="INFO" />
</category>
```

I assume, in your file `INFO` is replaced by `DEBUG`. So, switch back to `INFO` or a more higher level, such as `WARN` or `ERROR`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I have check out my $JBOSS_HOME/server/messaging/conf/jboss-log4j.xml but there are no category tag for "org.hibernate", if I add this tag on xml file so there is any need to add a appender for that or it will be work with out appender.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new file appender in log4j.properties file (create a new one if you dont have it) and do something like below to make those logs go into a seperate file of its own.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=SQL_APPENDER
```